# Parse fixed field lines from text file in Python with struct.unpack()?

Tags: python, struct

**TLDR:**

I want to parse the following line into an object:

```
 -rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw  169622962 2017-07-11 17:50 VID_20170711_175051.mp4
```

In reading the manual and various posts here, it seems that struct.unpack() is the way to go because directory listings are essentially fixed field tables.

But, I cannot find an example on how to do this, nor wrap my brain around it reading the docs.

Is this the correct approach? If so, can someone explain how to properly structure the format so that [struct.unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) can parse this?

**Background:**

In order to copy files off a phone using adb, I am using adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera to dump a directory listing of files. I want to parse the directory listing so that I know a) the name of each file that needs to be copied, and b) the file size so I can compare the file sizes after the copy to ensure the files were actually copied before they are deleted off the phone.

More sample data below.

```
 total 28G
 drwxrwx--x 593 root sdcard_rw  72K 2017-07-30 12:26 .
 drwxrwx--x   5 root sdcard_rw 4.0K 2017-07-30 12:24 ..
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 693K 2017-05-20 17:24 Burst_Cover_Collage_20170520172413.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 431K 2017-05-20 17:27 Burst_Cover_Collage_20170520172732.jpg
 drwxrwx--x   2 root sdcard_rw 4.0K 2017-01-22 15:08 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122150851
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 1.5M 2017-01-22 15:09 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122150851.gif
 drwxrwx--x   2 root sdcard_rw 4.0K 2017-01-22 15:09 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122150904
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.3M 2017-01-22 15:09 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122150904.gif
 drwxrwx--x   2 root sdcard_rw 4.0K 2017-01-22 15:13 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122151304
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 1.2M 2017-01-22 15:13 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122151304.gif
 drwxrwx--x   2 root sdcard_rw 4.0K 2017-01-22 15:14 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122151424
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 5.7M 2017-01-22 15:14 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170122151424.gif
 drwxrwx--x   2 root sdcard_rw 4.0K 2017-01-23 16:44 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170123164456
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 1.2M 2017-01-23 16:45 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170123164456.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 1.1M 2017-03-26 18:18 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170326181830.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 3.6M 2017-04-24 20:14 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170424201337.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 5.9M 2017-04-30 19:03 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170430190336.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 914K 2017-06-03 17:42 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170603174226.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.9M 2017-06-07 09:46 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170607094618.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 0.9M 2017-07-04 14:35 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170704143514.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 815K 2017-07-04 15:11 Burst_Cover_GIF_Action_20170704151104.gif
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.4M 2016-03-29 17:21 IMG_20160329_172126.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.4M 2016-03-29 17:21 IMG_20160329_172130.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.5M 2016-03-29 17:21 IMG_20160329_172131.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.4M 2016-03-29 17:21 IMG_20160329_172133.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.6M 2016-03-29 17:21 IMG_20160329_172133_1.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.8M 2016-03-29 19:40 IMG_20160329_194042.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.2M 2016-03-29 19:40 IMG_20160329_194044.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.3M 2016-03-29 19:40 IMG_20160329_194048.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.4M 2016-03-29 19:40 IMG_20160329_194052.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.0M 2016-03-29 19:40 IMG_20160329_194057.jpg
 -rw-rw----   1 root sdcard_rw 2.1M 2016-03-29 19:41 IMG_20160329_194100.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with re?

```
re.findall(r"([\d.]{1,3}[A-Z])\b(?:\s\S+){2}\s(?!\.{1,2}$)([\w\.]+)$", textfile, re.M)
```

Comment: Thank you. I considered regular expressions, however, I want to use this as a learning exercise to learn struct. I may, however, end up with regex anyway because the field size may change depending on values in each field (might be a constraint of struct).

Comment: @DrDamnit struct is for binary data. This is not binary data.